# How To Keep Running My App In Background Without Service?

Tags: android

My device is automatically removing my app from background when I send it to background after 2-3 minutes, and If my app removes from background with working process then if I open it again, it starts force closing. I want to keep it running in background without use service.

Is it possible?

Comment: Not this is not possible! =P

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible?

No.

When your app is no longer in the foreground, your process can be terminated at any time. That could be milliseconds, seconds, minutes, or hours after your app moves to the background. When it occurs depends on a number of environmental factors: version of Android, amount of system RAM, how busy the device is, etc.

Using a service does not change that, thought it is a signal to Android that your process is (hopefully) [actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html), and therefore your process should keep running a little bit longer.

If you do not wish to use a service, that is fine, but please do not expect your process to run for very long.

Comment: I have a screen recorder process. Other screen recorder apps havent service but they working in background

Comment: @Ataberk: Jake Wharton's [Telecine](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Telecine) uses a service. My [andcorder](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andcorder) uses a service. I would not expect any non-service implementation to be reliable. I do not know why you are trying to avoid using a service.